# Get an element from sorted set (set is from zrange, redis)

Tags: java, redis, jedis, sortedset

I am trying to get a specific element from a sorted set, which is from Jedis zrange.

Items stored in the set(key, value):

```
itemsInMarket, ABCD:0001:aaabbbcccddd
itemsInMarket, BCDEF:0003:bbbbccddeefffggggg
itemsInMarket, EFG:0015:dddddddeeffgghhiijjjjjjjj
(1000 more) ...
```

I get a sorted set using, `jedis.zrange("itemsInMarkets", 0, -1);`, and I am trying to get `BCDEF:0003:bbbbccddeefffggggg` from this set, which has 1000 items. But I cannot find how to do this, I need a little help here.

Also, is there a better way to get an element from a sorted set stored in Jedis?

Comment: Its depends do you retrieve the element by score or retrieve the score of the element?

Comment: why are you fetching the same string from the set, i thought you want to know whether the string exists in set<string> or not, you can use the contains function of set to know this.